# My Toolbar turned tranparent sometimes when scroll on pre-Lollipop

Tags: android, toolbar

Here is my xml code

```
        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/status_bar"
        tools:context=".app.activity.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

On Lollipop, it works well.
But pre-Lollipop, like 4.4, toobar will turn transparent sometimes when I scolled out window then scolled back.

Answer (score 0):

Make ToolBar in `tool_bar.xml`

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

After that include it in your `activity_main.xml` file like this

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    />
```

Finally you haven't to call AppBar

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">
```